# Circular import with Marshmallow nested relations

Tags: python, flask, schema

So here is the problem. Imagine I have three schema modules. For example.

`a.py`:

```
from models import A

class ASchema(ModelSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = A

    text = fields.String(required=True)
    bs = fields.Nested('BSchema', many=True, dump_only=True)
```

`c.py`:

```
from models import C

class CSchema(ModelSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = C

    text = fields.String(required=True)
    bs = fields.Nested('BSchema', many=True, dump_only=True)
```

`b.py`:

```
from models import B

class BSchema(ModelSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = B

    text = fields.String(required=True)
    as = fields.Nested(ASchema(exclude=ASchema.Meta.model.relations_keys), many=True, dump_only=True)
    cs = fields.Nested(CSchema(exclude=CSchema.Meta.model.relations_keys), many=True, dump_only=True)
```

The problem is that I can't import `BSchema` into `a.py` and `c.py`, but I need to exclude relations keys there too. How can I avoid circular import in this situation?

- I know there is an option of including everything in one module, but I keep that as a last resort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You state that your problem is that your can not "import `BSchema` into a.py and c.py", but it seems that what `ASchema` and `CSchema` depends on is class `B` (which is not defined anywhere in your snippet), not class `BSchema`, so one of your options is to split the "model" class definitions from the "ModelSchema" class definitions - so you'd have packages "a", "b" and "c" each with submodules "models.py" and "schemas.py", with "schemas.py" modules depending on "models" but "models" not depending on "schemas".

This being said, when you have such a tight coupling it quite often means your classes really belong to a same module...

edit: It looks like you already have your models in a distinct module, so I don't really understand what prevents you from referencing the models directly in the "schema" modules, ie:

```
# a.py
from wherever import ModelSchema, fields
from models import A, B

class ASchema(ModelSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = A

    text = fields.String(required=True)
    bs = fields.Nested(
            'BSchema', 
            exclude=B.relations_keys,
            many=True, 
            dump_only=True
            )

# c.py
from wherever import ModelSchema, fields
from models import C, B

class ASchema(ModelSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = C

    text = fields.String(required=True)
    bs = fields.Nested(
            'BSchema', 
            exclude=B.relations_keys,
            many=True, 
            dump_only=True
            )

# b.py
from wherever import ModelSchema, fields
from models import A, B, C

class BSchema(ModelSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = B

    text = fields.String(required=True)
    as = fields.Nested(
            "ASchema", 
            exclude=A.relations_keys, 
            many=True, 
            dump_only=True
            )
    cs = fields.Nested(
             "CSchema", 
             exclude=C.relations_keys, 
             many=True, 
             dump_only=True
             )
```

Note that

1. here "exclude" is a keyword arg of `fields.Nested()`, not of the nested `Schema` and
2. `fields.Nested()` first argument is supposed to be either a `Schema` *class* or a `Schema` class name, *not* a `Schema` *instance*.

Comment: I updated the question regarding the model declaration. Really in `BSchema` fields I just use `ASchema.Meta.model...` but just importing them works as well.

Comment: The problem with positioning them in one module is that if I declare `A` and `C` first, I can't use `B` in their fields because it's not declared yet and vice versa. How to work around that?

Comment: `A` and `C` do depend on `C` but here I'm using quotes. You can just reference a class in quotes and it is evaluated on runtime. However I would like to be able to access the class through instantiation so that I could add `exclude` statement.

Comment: Why would you instanciate the nested schemas here ??? `fields.Nested()` takes a `Schema` _class_ (or class name), **not** a `Schema` _instance as first argument, **and** it also takes an optional `exclude` argument - cf my edited answer.

Comment: Oh and yes - totally unrelated but `as` is a reserved word in Python ;)

Comment: `as` here is just like `a` in plural. Well you know if the class was `Post` it would be `posts`. I understand it's also a reserved word, but it's just some semi-pseudocode here. :) 

Other than that - you saved my day. I was absolutely sure that passing `exclude` to the `Scheme` instance is the only way. Thanks.